# ui-grid row height using rowHeight : 'auto'

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm getting this weird behavior from ui-grid which if I set the rowHeight to auto, each cell in a same row will have different height. One of the cells in each row will have multiline data, but apparently ui-grid will choke on that. (I colored the row so you can see what is wrong!) Any idea how to fix this? I mean to get same height for all the cells in each row. How do you handle different row heights in a same grid?

[image]

Comment: this is the problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ndmv6R0ebWWNN6Ab3yz

Comment: any updates?? same problem here...

Comment: Not really, as you can see in this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2656 , I was in touch with them but unfortunately, they don't wanna fix it....

Comment: no!! that's a disaster..it is really an important feature..., how can they ignore it?

Comment: any other grids you recommend..?

Comment: Depends on your need there are plenty. I had good experience with both jqGrid and EasyUI grid

Comment: This guy came up a nice and simple solution, probably it will work. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736036/1349365

Answer (score 4):

## Use CSS

```
[ui-grid-row] {
  display: table-row;
}

.ui-grid-row, .ui-grid-cell {
  height: auto!important;
}

.ui-grid-cell {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}

.ui-grid-header-cell, .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 2px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

## Use JavaScript

When you are using multiselect the height of the check column don't change, so you can set `enableRowHeaderSelection: false`. It will hide this column but still you can select the rows or if you want you can use this function from @jibap to align containers http://plnkr.co/edit/JwbEmPhJq2LInfUNncdi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization is pretty much impossible without pre-defined row heights. You'll find the same limitation with any virtualized list tool. Check [Ionic's collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) for instance.

The problem is that UI-Grid is only displaying a subset of all the rows at any given time, but in order for it make it *appear* like all the rows are there it has to create empty space around the rendered rows. If it doesn't know how tall all the rows are, it doesn't know how much empty space there should be.

If you wanted automatic row height it would have to render each row individually, measure it, then sum up all the heights. This would completely thrash the browser.